# Bayes theorem - posterior probability

Tags: bayes-theorem

Let's suppose, that we have 6 aces and two players.
Two aces are hearts, two diamonds and two spades.

The exercise says, that the first player picked two spades. The exercise asks me to determine aposteriori values of the possible combinations for the second player.

My attempt:
possible combination for the 2nd player are: 
 - two hearts,
 - two diamonds,
 - heart, diamond

If the player gets the one of these combination the probability of "heart diamond" should be twice higher than that of two hearts, two diamonds. I can add:
- diamond, spade
- heart spade

What's the logic behind posteriori probability? I know that it has to do something with conditional probability, but I cannot imagine how.

Comment: A priori, the probability for each combination with identical aces is $\frac{1}{15}$ and for each combination with different aces, it is $\frac{4}{15}$.

Comment: I think I got it. Let's P1 pick two spades. Then the posteriori probability for P2 of taking two hearts is 2/4 * 1/3 and for picking one heart and one diamond is 2 * 2/4 * 2/3.

Comment: Yes, you are right. A posteriori, there is only one mixed combination left. So, the probability is $\frac{1}{6}$ for the combinations with identical aces and $\frac{2}{3}$ for the combination with different aces.

Comment: I thought of two mixed combinations, I seem to be somewhat unconcentrated :)